# Angular2 router link with JSON parameter

Tags: angular2-routing

I have an angular2 application and I'm, having trouble with the back button.

I have a router link with a queryString paramater.  The parameter (named filter) has a value that's a JSON.

I have a router link defined as follows:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/app/listing', {filter: getFilter(model.id)}]">{{model.count}}</a>
```

The getFilter method does this:

```
getFilter(id) {
        return JSON.stringify({ Country: [id] });
    }
```

That returns as expression like this:

> "{"Country":[9]}"

I want a querystring like this.

> http://localhost:54675/app/listing?filter={"Country":[6]}

This is what Angular assemblies:

> http://localhost:54675/app/listing;filter=%7B%22Country%22:[6]%7D

URL Encoding changed the quotes and brackets.  I don't fully understand why the ? was replaced with ;.

This works fine and the listing page processes the filter.  However, if I drill down and then go back I get this error when calling JSON.Parse on the filter:

> Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0

When I first go to the page using the router link the filter value is:

> "{"Country":[6]}"

But when I use back the filter value is:

> "%7B%22Country%22:[6]%7D"

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?